# What does Discharging means on battery?

Tags: battery, battery-life

So I checked CPU - Z then I saw my battery status is discharging

Which scared me a little so I am here to ask..what does it mean?

Technology: Li-Ion

Health: Good

Voltage: 3722mV

Temperature 32.0°C (98.6°F)

Status: DisCharging

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Discharging** is the opposite of *charging*.

When you *charge* some electric component, such as a battery, you are storing potential electric energy in it.

When you **discharge** that battery, you are reversing the *charging* process and using the potential electric energy to drive other electric components.

Don't be scared, most of the time you are discharging your battery.

Reference: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/discharge (see **c** *electrical engineering*)

Answer (score 2):

Any electronic device must be powered somehow.

In case the device is not attached to an AC line,a charger, a powerbank or other external source, it draws needed  energy from the device battery. This state is called battery discharging, as the opposite to battery charging. The discharging current depends on power consumption of the device.

It is the same process if you power a flashlight, an MP3player or a camera by the included battery.